# Python API Request with Timestamp Parameter

Tags: python, json, api, request

I am trying to access trade data from the Gemini API for historical trade data - I need to provide timestamp arguments to make sure that I download exactly one day of trading data. The code example provided on the developer page returns all market trade data after the current timestamp, and looks like:

```
import requests, json
base_url = "https://api.gemini.com/v1"
response = requests.get(base_url + "/trades/btcusd")
btcusd_trades = response.json()
print(btcusd_trades)
```

Having tried this out, this provides all the fields I need, but only includes data after the timestamp of the actual request. This API uses the timestamp in number of seconds in a UNIX format since 1970-01-01 UTC, and I am trying to figure out how to incorporate this information as a request parameter so that I can customize the dates of the historical data that I need. So far, I've tried:

```
base_url = "https://api.gemini.com/v1"
params = {"since":"1643778000", "limit_trades":10000000}
response = requests.post(base_url + "/trades/btcusd",params=params)
btcusd_trades = response.json()
print(btcusd_trades)
```

This gives me the error: {'result': 'error', 'reason': 'EndpointNotFound', 'message': 'API entry point `/v1/trades/btcusd` not found'}. How can I format my request to get one day's worth of data?

Answer (score 0):

It appears the data given by https://api.gemini.com/v1/trades/btcusd is in a JSON format in which the whole thing is a list, and each item is a trade with attributes of timestamp, price, etc. This means you can grab all the data from the API and then *filter* by the timestamp you want. For example, you can do the following:

```py
import requests, json
base_url = "https://api.gemini.com/v1"
response = requests.get(base_url + "/trades/btcusd")
btcusd_trades = response.json()

i = 0
for i in range(len(btcusd_trades)):
    if btcusd_trades[i]["timestamp"] < 1643868816: # or any timestamp
        del btcusd_trades[i]
```

This will remove items from the response whose timestamp are before the intended UNIX parameter.